# Parameter passed from ajax call to wcf is received as null

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, wcf

Can someone help me out. The parameter passed from ajax to wcf is recived as null. I went through numerous post in stack overflow but could not find the fix. My code snippet is below. Thank you in anticipation.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/CustomServices/NewsService/getmyWork",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify({ itemType: "category" }),
    processData: true,
    success: function (result) { alert("success " + result); },
    error: function (error) { alert("failure " + error.statusText); }
});
```

The interface is

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "getmyWork/?itemType={itemType}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    SolutionV1.CustomServices.NewsService.DynamicItemsContext DoWork(string itemType);
};
```

Service Method

```
    public DynamicItemsContext DoWork(string itemType)
    {
        var items = RetrieveItems(itemType);
        var context = new DynamicItemsContext();
        context.Items = items.ToList();
        context.TotalCount = items.Count();
        return context;
    }
```

Comment: You declared itemType in the url as a query parameter but you're passing it as a POST's body content.

Answer (score 0):

Your WCF method is setup as a http post method but you uri template suggests the parameter will be passed as a query string parameter on the URL.

As you are making a POST request your data will be passed in the request body and not in the URL.

Try changing the URI template for your method to get rid of the query string.